# Can i query directly Redis database (persistent not in-memory) or data is always kept in-memory and requests are executed against the in-memory data?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

A simple question about using Redis as a persistent database (not in-memory):

Can I directly query the Redis database from my spring boot application (just like with MySQL or Oracle db) or data should always be loaded in-memory first and requests are to be executed against the in-memory data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is an in-memory database which you can treat like any other external dependency you may have in your application. Compared with the other databases you mentioned, it does not offer the ability to use SQL to query it, so you must rely on [its own commands](https://redis.io/commands/), which are very specific.

There are some [Java clients](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_java/) you can use to interact with Redis, including Lettuce and Jedis. The commands you send to Redis are executed against the data that Redis itself keep in its own memory.

Comment: Hi Efran, Redis can also be used as a persistent storage and my question is regarding that only.

Comment: Redis is an in-memory database. Data can be persisted to disk according to different options but this is transparent to the clients (with the exception of the `BGSAVE` command); there are no commands to instruct Redis to "load" data from disk as the data is already loaded in memory in the first place.

Comment: Tnx Efran. One quick question. I am using jedis to save data into redis database. And i am using RedisInsight to view this data (keys). If this data is really in-memory why it does not get deleted if i restart my redis server OR my laptop. I tried both option but data still exists. Any idea?

Comment: You are welcome @khush. You may configure Redis to persist your data to file and reload it upon restart: I believe you may have one such a file holding old data which is automatically reloaded on your PC. Check your redis.conf for the config option `dbfilename`. Deleting it and restarting Redis should bring you with an empty database.

Comment: Yes I believe so. I am running ubuntu on windows to install redis and running it. I tried looking for this file and delete the data file(dump.rdb) but it is hard to find that find in a folder through ubuntu. Another short question please : If i want to refresh my redis data through a daily running job i believe i have to write data directly to redis database along with choosing a persistent option (AOF or RDB) in case job fails in the middle. Does redis replace this data file or it can take backup for the last datafile and then create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

When you query data from Redis it does not load that data in memory at that point. Redis is an in-memory database, meaning it always keeps all the data in it's memory, and when you send the query to redis, it processes it against the data that is already in memory.